# How group days with time slot to know if I have a all week in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table contains weekly slots with this columns :

```
| [id] | [dayOfWeek] | [startTime] | [endTime]
```

This table correspond with time slot when the shop is open :
*ex : (1, 2, 14:00:00, 16:00:00) ==> the shop is open Tuesday (2nd day of week) between 14h and 16h.*

How can I know with a sql function if I have the same time slot (*ex: 14h => 16h*) for each days of a week ?

**EDIT**

This is an example of my data :

```
| id | dayOfWeek | startTime | endTime  |
|====|===========|===========|==========|
| 1  |     1     | 07:00:00  | 08:00:00 |
| 2  |     1     | 09:00:00  | 10:00:00 |
| 3  |     0     | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 |
| 4  |     1     | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 |
| 5  |     2     | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 |
| 6  |     3     | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 |
| 7  |     4     | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 |
| 8  |     5     | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 |
| 9  |     6     | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 |
| 10 |     3     | 16:00:00  | 19:00:00 |
| 11 |     5     | 13:00:00  | 23:00:00 |
```

I want that my request return :

```
| dayOfWeek | startTime | endTime  |
|===========|===========|==========|
|     1     | 07:00:00  | 08:00:00 |
|     1     | 09:00:00  | 10:00:00 |
|           | 14:00:00  | 18:00:00 | --> my all week (id 3 --> 9)
|     3     | 16:00:00  | 19:00:00 |
|     5     | 13:00:00  | 23:00:00 |
```

Comment: you have day of week, but nothing separating the weeks from each other.... how can you tell which where a week begins and ends, or does ID1 = week 1 for year 1901?

Comment: This might be a "shop's regular hours" table and as such doesn't need to vary per week. I smell a homework problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN DROP TABLE #TestData; END;

    CREATE TABLE #TestData (
        id INT NOT NULL,
        [dayOfWeek] TINYINT NOT NULL,
        startTime TIME(0) NOT NULL,
        endTime TIME(0) NOT NULL 
        );
    INSERT #TestData(id, dayOfWeek, startTime, endTime) VALUES
        (1 , 1, '07:00:00', '08:00:00'),
        (2 , 1, '09:00:00', '10:00:00'),
        (3 , 0, '14:00:00', '18:00:00'),
        (4 , 1, '14:00:00', '18:00:00'),
        (5 , 2, '14:00:00', '18:00:00'),
        (6 , 3, '14:00:00', '18:00:00'),
        (7 , 4, '14:00:00', '18:00:00'),
        (8 , 5, '14:00:00', '18:00:00'),
        (9 , 6, '14:00:00', '18:00:00'),
        (10, 3, '16:00:00', '19:00:00'),
        (11, 5, '13:00:00', '23:00:00');

    --=====================================

 SELECT 
    td1.startTime,
    td1.endTime,
    dw.daysOfWeek
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            td.startTime,
            td.endTime          
        FROM
            #TestData td
        ) td1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            STUFF((
                SELECT 
                    CONCAT(', ', td2.dayOfWeek)
                FROM
                    #TestData td2
                WHERE
                    td1.startTime = td2.startTime
                    AND td1.endTime = td2.endTime
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '')
            ) dw (daysOfWeek);
```

Results:

```
startTime        endTime          daysOfWeek
---------------- ---------------- -------------------------
07:00:00         08:00:00         1
09:00:00         10:00:00         1
13:00:00         23:00:00         5
14:00:00         18:00:00         0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
16:00:00         19:00:00         3
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot ! Yes, it's almost that but I want the request return also the other time slot not include in the week.

Comment: @JasonALong - Thanks a lot ! This solution help me a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The following returns `id`s that are open on 14:00 - 16:00 on every day of the week:

```
select id
from t
where startTime <= '14:00:00' and endTime >= '16:00:00'
group by id
having count(*) = 7
```

Comment: This should work, except if the data has duplicate or overlapping hours (presuming this is a homework problem, so...). It even handles the case where a shop has a break in hours on one day (say, open 0800-1200, and then open 1300-1800, it'll still match the second row)

Comment: Thanks ! But this doesn't answer to my problem. I don't know the startTime and the endTime. I've to group when it's the same.

I've edit my question with an example